# Cannot iterate through CSV columns

Tags: java, loops, csv, finance, stock

I'm building a stock screener that applies a calculation through each column of a csv file. However, when I run the for loop, I only get one result back.

```
    String path = "C:/Users/0/Desktop/Git/Finance/Data/NQ100.csv";
    Reader buf = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));
    CSVParser parsed = new CSVParser(buf, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader()
            .withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());

    // Parse tickers
    Map<String, Integer> header = parsed.getHeaderMap();
    List<String> tickerList = new ArrayList<>(header.keySet());

    for (int x=1; x < tickerList.size(); x++) { <----------------------- PROBLEM

        // Accessing closing price by Header names
        List<Double> closeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CSVRecord record : parsed) {
            String stringClose = record.get(x);
            Double close = Double.valueOf(stringClose);
            closeList.add(close);
        }

        // Percentage Change
        List<Double> pctList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=1; i < closeList.size(); i++) {
            Double pct = closeList.get(i) / closeList.get(i-1) - 1;
            pctList.add(pct);
        }

        // Statistics
        Double sum = 0.0, var = 0.0, mean, sd, rfr, sr;
        // Mean
        for (Double num : pctList) sum += num;
        mean = sum/pctList.size();
        // Standard Deviation
        for (Double num: pctList) var += Math.pow(num - mean, 2);
        sd = Math.sqrt(var/pctList.size());
        // Risk Free Rate
        rfr = Math.pow((1+0.03),(1/252.0))-1;
        // Sharpe Ratio
        sr = Math.sqrt(252) * ((mean-rfr)/sd);

        System.out.println(tickerList.get(x) + " " + sr);
    }
```

My data looks like this:

```
,AAL,AAPL,ADBE
2007-10-25,26.311651,23.141403,47.200001
2007-10-26,26.273216,23.384495,47.0
2007-10-29,26.004248,23.43387,47.0
```

So I was expecting:

```
AAL XXX
AAPL XXX
ADBE XXX
```

But I got just:

```
AAL 0.3604941921663456
```

Would be grateful if you guys can help me find the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through `Iterable` in *Java* only once, in your case `CSVParser parsed` implements `Iterable<CSVRecord>`.

So you iterate through it only for the first time when you calculate statistics for **AAL**, during analyzing data for **AAPL** and **ADBE** it will be handled as an empty one.

You can handle this by introducing helper list init by the `parsed`, add next code (it is a one line solution of course e.g. in Java 8, but this option will work for earlier versions too) before the `for` cycle:

```
    List<CSVRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CSVRecord record : parsed) {
        records.add(record);
    }
```

And change next line:

```
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
```

with:

```
for (CSVRecord record : parsed) {
```

---

For the CSV you've provided you will have next output then:

```
AAL -21.583101145880306
AAPL 23.417753561072438
ADBE -16.75343297000953
```

Comment: Wow, thanks marme1ad, it worked flawlessly and with great explaination! So it appears that **records** is a list of iterable **record** (rows). That seems to have the net effect of creating another buffer for the entire dataset. If so, is there a more efficient way of dealing with these iterator problems, or is this the standard solution? And, would creating the **records list** still make Apache CSV more efficient than parsing the CSV manually (without creating CSVRecord/Parse objects) like **user3043452** suggested? Thanks!!!

Comment: @JamesShen, `CSVParser` is good to use since it encapsulates _CSV_ parsing functionality. Assuming _CSV_ is not too big and easily manageable in memory I would recommend to split your logic into 2 parts: first will use `CSVParser` and will prepare `Map<String, List<Double>>` with _CSV_ headers as key and list of closing prices as a value; and second will calculate statistics based on this map.

Answer (score 0):

So here's a block of the code that work for me, if i understand your question, you only want to "read" each column and row from a csv file, hope helps.

```
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(archivo), "UTF8"));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {                
            if(a!=0){
                String[] datos = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                System.out.println(datos[0] + " - " + datos[1] + " - " + datos[2]);
            }
            a++;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I was going to parse the CSV manually like this if I couldn't get Apache Commons to work. marme1ad found that CSVParser could only be iterated through once. But yeah, parsing them manually like this would allow easier looping. Thanks!